# Use of singular verb with plural noun for one to one mapping?

Tags: verb-agreement

I think this sentence is incorrect

**The various plots corresponds to different numerical values of parameters.**

However, I want to know if there exists a one to one mapping between the parameter value and the corresponding plot, will this sentence make sense or its still wrong?

P.S.-can I add **respectively** in the sentence to denote one to one mapping

**The various plots corresponds to different numerical values of parameters, respectively.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first is incorrect because of its lack of subject-verb agreement—but *not* in the way you are pointing out.

It should be:

> The various plots **correspond** to different numerical values.

The subject (*plots*) is plural so the verb also needs to be.

Note that I removed *of parameters*, because it sounds awkward.

With that rephrasing, there is nothing wrong with the sentence.

---

Your edit doesn't address the actual problem, and adding *respectively* as you did is just strange. There aren't stated individual things that each item can be said to correspond to *in sequence*.

*Respectively* would normally be used in one of these formulations:

> The old cars and the new cars were respectively green and blue.
>   The old cars and the new cars were green and blue, respectively.

---

If you want to stress the individual plots, then you could instead write something like this:

> **Each** plot **corresponds** to a different numerical **value**.